# Iterate through file but ignore certain line break characters?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, line-breaks

I know that I can read the entire file into memory and simply replace the offending character in memory then iterate through the stored file, **but I don't want to do that** because these are MASSIVE text files (often exceeding 4GB).

With that said, I want to iterate line by line through a file (which has been properly encoded as utf-8 using codecs) but I don't want line breaks to occur on the `\x0b` (`\v`) character. Unfortunately, there is some binary data that shows up in my file that has the `\x0b` character. Naturally, this causes a line break which ends up splitting up some lines that I need to keep intact. I'd like to ignore this character when determining where line breaks should occur while iterating through the file.

Is there a parameter or approach that will enable me to do this? I'm ok with writing my own generator to iterate line by line through the file by specifying my own valid line break characters, but I'm not sure if there isn't a simpler approach, and I'm not sure how to do this since I'm using the codecs library to handle encoding.

Here are some (sanitized) sample data:

```
Record#|EventID|Date| Time-UTC|Level|computer name|param_01|param_02|param_03|param_04|param_05|param_06|source name|event log
84491|682|03/19/2015| 21:59:16.000|a-pass|WKS-WINXP32BIT|sample_user|SampleGroup|(0x0,0xF38058)|RDP-Tcp#12|RogueApp|10.3.98.6|Security|C:\Users\sampleuser\EventLogs\problem-child\SecEvent.Evt
90582|682|04/03/2015| 14:42:14.000|a-pass|WKS-WINXP32BIT|sample_user|SampleGroup|(0x0,0x35BDF)|RDP-Tcp#5|RogueApp|10.3.98.14|Security|C:\Users\sampleuser\EventLogs\problem-child\SecEvent.Evt
90613|682|04/03/2015| 16:26:03.000|a-pass|WKS-WINXP32BIT|sample_user|SampleGroup|(0x0,0x35BDF)|RDP-Tcp#9|Anonymous's Mac|192.168.1.14ì°†éªá…°ê±ºà¨€Aà¨€Aì°†éªá… ê±ºà¬€Aà¬€Aé¶é«á… Ö Î„|Security|C:\Users\sampleuser\EventLogs\problem-child\SecEvent.Evt
90626|682|04/03/2015| 16:57:35.000|a-pass|WKS-WINXP32BIT|sample_user|SampleGroup|(0x0,0x35BDF)|RDP-Tcp#11|RogueApp|10.3.98.14|Security|C:\Users\sampleuser\EventLogs\problem-child\SecEvent.Evt
91018|682|04/04/2015| 13:56:13.000|a-pass|WKS-WINXP32BIT|sample_user|SampleGroup|(0x0,0x100513C)|RDP-Tcp#33|Anonymous|10.3.58.13|Security|C:\Users\sampleuser\EventLogs\problem-child\SecEvent.Evt
91038|682|04/04/2015| 14:09:19.000|a-pass|WKS-WINXP32BIT|sample_user|SampleGroup|(0x0,0x100513C)|RDP-Tcp#39|Anonymous's Mac|192.168.1.18ì°†éªá…°ê±ºæ¸€xæ¸€xì°†éªá… ê±ºæ¬€xæ¬€xé¶é«á… Ð€Ì€|Security|C:\Users\sampleuser\EventLogs\problem-child\SecEvent.Evt
91064|682|04/04/2015| 15:25:33.000|a-pass|WKS-WINXP32BIT|ACN-Helpdesk|WKS-WINXP32BIT|(0x0,0x11FA916)|RDP-Tcp#43|CONTROLLER|10.3.58.4|Security|C:\Users\sampleuser\EventLogs\problem-child\SecEvent.Evt
91163|682|04/04/2015| 16:40:19.000|a-pass|WKS-WINXP32BIT|Anonymous|SampleGroup|(0x0,0x37D49)|RDP-Tcp#2|Anonymous's Mac|192.168.1.18ì°†éªá…°ê±ºá´€æ®–á´€æ®–ì°†éªá… ê±ºã¬€æ®–ã¬€æ®–é¶é«á… Ð€Ì€|Security|C:\Users\sampleuser\EventLogs\problem-child\SecEvent.Evt
91204|682|04/04/2015| 18:10:55.000|a-pass|WKS-WINXP32BIT|Anonymous|SampleGroup|(0x0,0x37D49)|RDP-Tcp#5|Anonymous's Mac|192.168.1.18ì°†éªá…°ê±ºæ˜€æ˜€ì°†éªá… ê±ºæ„€æ„€é¶é«á… Ð€Ì€|Security|C:\Users\sampleuser\EventLogs\problem-child\SecEvent.Evt
91545|682|04/05/2015| 13:41:58.000|a-pass|WKS-WINXP32BIT|Anonymous|SampleGroup|(0x0,0x37D49)|RDP-Tcp#7|Anonymous's Mac|192.168.1.14ì°†éªá…°ê±ºìˆ€ìˆ€ì°†éªá… ê±ºëŒ€ëŒ€é¶é«á… Ð€Ì€|Security|C:\Users\sampleuser\EventLogs\problem-child\SecEvent.Evt
91567|682|04/05/2015| 14:42:21.000|a-pass|WKS-WINXP32BIT|Anonymous|SampleGroup|(0x0,0x37D49)|RDP-Tcp#9|Anonymous's Mac|192.168.1.14ì°†éªá…°ê±ºæ €æ €ì°†éªá… ê±ºæ„€æ„€é¶é«á… Ð€Ì€|Security|C:\Users\sampleuser\EventLogs\problem-child\SecEvent.Evt
92120|682|04/06/2015| 19:06:43.000|a-pass|WKS-WINXP32BIT|ACN-Helpdesk|WKS-WINXP32BIT|(0x0,0x3D6DB)|RDP-Tcp#2|Anonymous's Mac|192.168.1.14ì°†éªá…°ê±ºç„€ç„€ì°†éªá… ê±ºçœ€çœ€é¶é«á… Ð€Ì€|Security|C:\Users\sampleuser\EventLogs\problem-child\SecEvent.Evt
```

It parses everything fine except for the very last row. Yes I know there shouldn't be binary data in a CSV file, but there is. And I have no choice in that matter.

Comment: take a look at the builtin `fileinput` module

Comment: @JoranBeasley I don't see how that will help me since it also detects line breaks by itself based on what I can tell. Please elaborate if I'm mistaken.

Comment: I dont think it breaks lines on `0x0b`  I dont think any of them will break on that ... are you sure you dont mean `\x0a` ?

Comment: No it's definitely \x0b which is equivalent to \v (vertical tab) in Python

Comment: whoa you are right ... heh I had never seen that before ... regardless it should not be ... are you sure it counts as a linebreak thought `"a\va".splitlines()`

Comment: @Joran the codecs library creates a line break where it encounters this character, yes.

Comment: While it seems fairly simple implementing a data reader that reads chunks in until it finds a newline then yields that line based on the characters I give it, it seems *deceptively* simple. For instance, I'm currently using the codecs library to handle encoding/decoding, and I'd have to do that myself. I'm thinking there are lots of pitfalls or gotchas I'm not aware of for this approach.

Comment: ok I gotta go I'll check back later for any more insight you might have to help me help solve your problem

Comment: Perhaps use `io.open` (which is faster and not pseudodeprecated liked `codecs`). Does `io.open` treat `\v` as a newline?

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm leaning in that direction. I'm not sure if it treats that as a newline or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> with open("out.test","wb") as f:
...    f.write("a\va\nb\rq")
...
>>> for line in open("out.test","rb"):
...    print line.decode("utf8")
...
a♂a

q
```

seems fine in python 2.7 ... what kind of encoding is this file that this wont work?

Comment: I opened the file using codecs and encoded as utf-8. The data shows as u"\x0b" in the string

Comment: It is surrounded by Unicode code points which may affect its behavior also. In some cases, lines don't include the character, while in others it is the final character (but a line break is always created where the character occurs). I need to use a generator to iterate line by line, not load it all into RAM with splitlines() (I have one input file that is at least 12GB)

Comment: Ideally I can find a solution using the codecs library that allows me to specify which newline character to avoid, but I fear I may need to handle file iteration myself.